# Minesweeper mine generation algorithm

Tags: algorithm, minesweeper

I am making a minesweeper clone. My current algorithm for mine generation is just: pick a coordinate, if it has no mine, place a mine, else try again. I think this is not an efficient algorithm, especially in high density minefields. I am looking at some other options like: Fisher-Yates shuffle and the likes, but I think it has a long running time for much larger grids. I am thinking of using Linked Lists. Any suggestions?

Comment: put all possible locations in a list. shuffle the list and put bombs in the first x locations.

Comment: Just use the Fisher-Yates shuffle to randomize the indices and then pick the number of mines from 0 to that number

Comment: ohh. thanks! I will try those. But are there any other solutions that can reduce unnecessary work? For example, do I really need to shuffle the WHOLE list? Anyways, I think I'll stick with shuffling, it's simpler and more manageable

Comment: @userx01 you don't need to shuffle the whole list, you just need to pick a random index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list/array where you can get size of list in constant time you may give a try to following:

```
list = List of all fields
N = number of mines
N.times do
  index = random(list.size)
  pick list[index]
  list.remove(index)
end
```

This way:

- you don't need to shuffle whole list
- you avoid picking up same fields 2 times

In short it will be just drawing random field from list and removing it from list to avoid collision on next draw.

Comment: Yes! That's what I'm looking for. Great help, thanks! Btw, can this be achieved using only arrays? (for languages without data structures)

Comment: I think what you are searching for is rather Vector than list. By default pure list data structure has no constant time size() method and remove() method.

Comment: Let's say I have a 2d array for the minefield. Then I will make another list then pick X indices, right? So at the very least I'm copying the whole array?